# missing symbol names in perf top but not in perf record/report

Tags: linux, performance, perf

An application (compiled with -g and -fno-omit-frame-pointer) is running
inside the linux container. Trying to use perf tool on the linux host (not
inside the container) to identify a list of functions consuming more cpu
cycles.
Running perf top -p `pidof app` on the linux host prints address instead of
symbol name, where-as perf record -p `pidof app` and perf report prints
symbol names instead of addresses.

Why doesn't perf top display symbol names if perf record/report can?

Linux host (x86_64) is based on jammy, and Linux container is based on bionic.

Appreciate any help.